# Can somebody explain to me what 'void postConcat' in Android does?

Tags: android, linear-algebra

So I have 2 matrices.

Colormatrix and Threshold.
Colormatrix is initially,

```
C =  [  0.213 0.715 0.072 0 0;
        0.213 0.715 0.072 0 0;
        0.213 0.715 0.072 0 0;
           0    0     0   1 0;]
```

and threshold is:

```
T = [   255 0 0 1 -306;
        0 255 0 1 -306;
        0 0 255 1 -306;
        0 0  0  1 -306;]
```

Now this line of code in android `colorMatrix.postConcat(threshold);`
returns this:

```
C =  [  54.315 182.325 18.36 1 -306;
        54.315 182.325 18.36 1 -306;
        54.315 182.325 18.36 1 -306;
           0      0      0   1   0; ]
```

Why? What are the steps that it follows to come to that result?

If I do the same thing in Matlab, that is `C*T'`
I get this:

```
C =  [  54.315 182.325 18.36 0;
        54.315 182.325 18.36 0;
        54.315 182.325 18.36 0;
           0      0      0   0; ]
```

A different dimension array with different values. Can somebody explain to me what postConCat does? I can't find anything online about this function, only in the Android documentation, and it says only this:

```
Concat this colormatrix with the specified postmatrix.
```

. Is it only an Android thing?

Comment: I dont get what you are trying to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why? What are the steps that it follows to come to that result?

The source code for ColorMatrix can be viewed here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.java

> Is it only an Android thing?

I believe it kinda is, more like only a ColorMatrix thing. In Android, I believe ColorMatrix is only provided as a way to construct a special `ColorFilter` (`ColorMatrixColorFilter`) which is used mainly to be applied to `Bitmap` objects.

From the `ColorMatrix.postConcat` description:

> This is logically the same as calling setConcat(postmatrix, this)

And from the description for `setConcat`:

> Set this colormatrix to the concatenation of the two specified colormatrices, such that the resulting colormatrix has the same effect as applying matB and then applying matA.

So, if understand it correctly, I believe `ColorMatrix.postConcat` can be used to combine two ColorMatrix objects into one so you can then just apply it once to the Bitmap of your choice instead of doing it twice.

In short, if you want to have the same behavior with what you get in Matlab, you might need to implement it yourself.